# Installing Windows 10 without losing data

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, mbr, gpt, partition-recovery

I have a 750 GB HDD with two partitions.
One partition has 550 GB with my files so I want to save it.
The other partition had Windows 7 on it.

So I booted Windows 10 from USB, formatted the Windows 7 partition but I was unable to install Windows 10 because it requires GPT partition table. The current table format is MBR.

So now I am unable to install Windows 10, also I am unable to install Windows 7 because in will not boot, giving some disk error.

I booted again from Windows 10, deleted the formatted Windows 7 partition, tried to create it again, but the space remains unallocated.

I don't want to loose my files so I can't reformat the entire hard drive as GPT. DISKPART will only list the entire HDD so I can't work with it.

Any suggestions please, to save my data and install Windows 10?

Comment: If you already formatted the drive, I don’t understand, Windows 10 also supports MBR.  Requires you to enable legacy mode in order to boot into the installation environment in the supported mode.

Comment: I don't know what to do. I can't copy my files to an external hdd because I don't have an installed os. Legacy mode is enabled but only Windows 10 is able to boot but I can't install it because of partition table error.

Comment: If you enable Legacy Mode/CSM and have booted into the Windows installation environment then you should absolutely be able to select a partition and install Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: **make backups now**. If that data has any value to you, you should make regular backups. Hardware sometimes fails, humans make mistakes, malware is doing its malware stuff. You must have backups of anything that you can't loose.

You can install either Windows 7 or Windows 10 on MBR disk, but you have to boot the installation media in CSM mode (aka. BIOS mode aka. legacy). It sounds like you're booting in EFI mode, which makes Windows require GPT.

So:

1. Make backups, don't take risks.
2. Boot in CSM mode instead of EFI mode.
3. Install Windows as usual.

Comment: I don't know how to backup my files without having an installed os on my computer. My bios only let's me to enable/Disable legacy mode, I have no other options regarding boot method. Legacy mode was always enabled. If I disable it, the Windows 10 flash drive is not listed in boot device list.

Comment: How did you get the Windows 10 flash drive? Did you create it yourself?

Comment: It is an original windows 10, probably, it is not mine. I did not created the usb drive myself. Is it possible to have it burned in a wrong way on the USB flash drive? I just received it with the serial number written on a piece of paper.

Comment: @JDoe - Yes;  You will need to create the installation media yourself and make sure its created to support legacy mode.

Comment: @Ramhound Why do you think this flash drive is not suitable?

Comment: @JDoe There are methods to create these USB drive just for EFI boot, just for CSM boot or for both. If you can't see it as a bootable device with legacy boot disabled, it's possible that it has been tampered with and can only be used for legacy installs now... but that would not explain problems with GPT. What errors are you getting exactly?

Comment: @gronostaj  - The author knows nothing about how the installation media was created.  There is a good chance it was made with Rufus, specifically to support UEFI, I don't trust the lack of information about the drive.  The author claims their system has CSM already enabled, had they attempted to boot into the installation environment, they wouldn't have gotten the MBR error message if the drive was properly formatted to support CSM.  Easier for me to say toss the drive, recreate it properly, then try to diagnose something the author won't be able to diagnose.

Comment: @JDoe Regarding backups: Use another PC to create a bootable Ubuntu flash drive, boot it and use it to make a copy of your files to reliable external media.

Comment: @Ramhound _"If I disable [legacy boot], the Windows 10 flash drive is not listed in boot device list."_

Comment: @gronostaj - If that is the case, there isn't a problem, the author simply selects the now unallocated partition.  *The question really should be updated to reflect the current state of affairs.*  Since the author should not be getting an error message about being unable to install due to MBR.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys. Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I will try ți backup with Ubuntu first( 500gb of data will take forever on USB 2.0). Then I will create a bootable flash drive with new Windows. I will give you feedback about the results. Thanks.

Comment: This is the error I get when booting. Same is happening when booting from a Windows 7 dvd. I can not create the partition again. The space is unallocated after deleting the partition. "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. the selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI system, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks"

Comment: That means you're in fact booting in EFI mode. Whether legacy boot is enabled or not shouldn't affect this. You have to boot in legacy/CSM mode.

Comment: Legacy is enabled in bios while I get this error. Maybe both, flash drive and dvd are burned for the wrong partition table. As a last resort, I will (hopefully) be able to backup my data and use diskpart to recreate the partition table. Thanks

Comment: DVD is always bootable both with EFI and CSM. You are probably not selecting the right boot entry.

Comment: Is it possible to select a wrong boot entry if I am able to get to the step where I have to create the partition?

Comment: Yes, both will be bootable. Your UEFI always enables EFI boot and you have legacy enabled in addition to it. It's Windows' limitation that partitioning scheme is tied to boot mode.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, thanks guys. I used Rufus to write the windows for MBR/BIOS to the USB flash drive. After booting, I was able to create a partition from the unallocated space and windows is now installed. Saved my files and windows is running fine. Thanks again.

Comment: That should have been a comment, sorry.